# How to replace a numeric field value with its attribute?

Tags: r

My df

```
df = structure(list(record_id = c("8472", "6648"), 
               ne_nombre = c("John",
                             "Peter"), 
               ne_cc = c("1234", "5678"), 
               ne_idatencion = c(1111, 2222), 
               nom_ips = structure(1:2, 
                                   redcapLabels = c("Store 1",
                                                    "Store 2"), 
                                   redcapLevels = 1:2), 
               ev_faudit = c("2022-04-27 09:48",
                             "2022-04-27 12:49"), 
               ev_nomusuar = c("jane", "joe"), 
               
               ev_obs2 = c("pending", 
                           "pending")
               ), 
          row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                            "data.frame"))
```

The field `df$nom_ips` is a numeric type field which includes attribute data. I require to replace its numeric field with its associated label so `df$nom_ips` ends up being  `Store 1  Store 2`

I have tried this with no luck :

```
. <- attr(df11$nom_ips, "redcapLabels")
df11$nom_ips1 <- factor(df11$nom_ips, ., names(.))

Error in factor(df11$nom_ips, ., names(.)) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the argument name

```
df11$nom_ips1 <- factor(df11$nom_ips, levels = attr(df11$nom_ips,"redcapLevels"),
    labels = attr(df11$nom_ips, "redcapLabels"))
```

-output

```
> df11$nom_ips1
[1] Store 1 Store 2
Levels: Store 1 Store 2
```

---

Or use `do.call` after changing the `attribute` names with `labels` and `levels`

```
 do.call(factor, c(list(df11$nom_ips), 
    setNames(attributes(df11$nom_ips), c("labels", "levels"))))
[1] Store 1 Store 2
Levels: Store 1 Store 2
```